Calculate structure/class size at compile time based on list of members
This task arised while implementing a system for counting memory used by objects.
I have calcClassSize function that accepts an object of type S and a parameter pack of all S fields. The parameter pack is necessary since for each field an additional function getExtraUsedMemory(field) needs to be called, to count used heap memory as well.
However here we have a problem that it's possible to forget one or more fields.
I'd like to be able to check at compile-time that no field is skipped.
In other words, I want to make a compile-time function calcMembersSize, that would accept the same parameter pack of all the fields, calculate object size based on this list, and compare the result with sizeof(S). Obviously such calculation will need to account for possible presence of vtable pointers and base subobjects. (That's why Boost.PFR doesn't fit the bill, since it requires standard layout).
#include <iostream>


template <typename T, typename... Members>
consteval size_t calcMembersSize(Members&&... members) 
{
    // ?
}

struct B {
    virtual void v() {}
};

struct C {
    virtual void w() {}
};

struct D {
    int j;
};

struct E {};

struct A : B, C, D 
{
    int i;
    double d;
    short s;
    bool b;
    std::string str;
    char c;
};

template <typename T, typename... Members>
size_t calcClassSize(const T& object, Members&&... members) 
{
    static_assert(calcMembersSize<T>(std::forward<Members>(members)...) == sizeof(T));
    ...        
    // add up sizes of all fields + result of getExtraSize(f)
}


int main() {  
    A a;    
    static_assert(calcMembersSize<A>(a.i, a.d, a.s, a.b, a.str, a.c) == sizeof(a));

    static_assert(calcMembersSize<A>(a.d, a.s, a.c, a.b, a.str) != sizeof(a));
    static_assert(calcMembersSize<A>(a.i, a.s, a.c, a.b, a.str) != sizeof(a));
    static_assert(calcMembersSize<A>(a.i, a.d, a.c, a.b, a.str) != sizeof(a));
    static_assert(calcMembersSize<A>(a.i, a.d, a.s, a.str) != sizeof(a));
    static_assert(calcMembersSize<A>(a.i, a.d, a.s, a.str) != sizeof(a));
}

I understand that the task is probably not solvable in general, but I'm willing to accept some imperfections, namely we can assume that:

Fields are passed in the same order as they appear in S declaration
C++20
It's ok if the solution works only on GCC13
There're no virtual bases and no custom alignas members
I'd even tolerate a formal UB provided it works now on GCC (and then will migrate to C++26 reflection).

Please tell if it is possible to implement such calculation at compile time and how?

@KamilCuk No that doesn't work because for each field we also need to add the result of getExtraSize(field), to count memory on the heap that might be used by pointer-like fields.

I don't get why you would ever need those functions since the built-in sizeof operator already gives you the size of the class at compile-time (and it won't "forget fields")

@Fareanor But it doesn't count heap memory for pointer-like members, that's why I need to also call getExtraSize() for each field.

This question is similar to: Why is the size of a tuple or struct not the sum of the members?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@BoP That question is about Rust, this question is about C++. Also I'm not seeking for an explanation of padding, I need a solution that would be able to calculate total size while taking possible padding into account.

in general you cannot know if an object allocates additional memory internally and even if you could, it is impossible to know at compile time. What is your task exactly?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I don't need to calcClassSize to work at compile time. I need only to calcMembersSize to work at compile time, to check that the list of all fields passed to calcClassSize is complete. We can assume that for every field f, getExtraUsedMemory(f) will return the amount of heap memory used by that field (and it is called at runtime only).

@AlexJenter But for memory allocated on the heap, you cannot know at compile-time (since such allocations happen at runtime). Moreover, without additional knowledge (end terminator, etc...) you cannot know if a pointer points to one, two, ten, or as many elements you want.

Sorry, got a Rust link by mistake. Here is the C++ version Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?

@Fareanor I don't need to get the amount of heap memory at compile time. At compile time, I only want to check that the list of fields passed to calcClassSize is complete, that's all. One more time: calcClassSize works at run time. But inside, it will contain a static_assert that would check that the list of fields is complete by calling  calcMembersSize and comparing it to sizeof(T).

It just occurred to me that having a consteval function fields_count() would also fit the bill. I'd be able to compare the result with sizeof...(members).

Again, sizeof operator will give you the size of the class at compile-time and won't miss any class member. I still don't understand why you would ever need that calcMembersSize() function. It's just adding boilerplate for nothing. You could easily implement it with fold-expressions, but still, getting members sizes individually will make you miss the possible padding.

There are a lot more cases you would need to exclude. It already fails in that it is impossible to obtain a list of base classes of a given class. You can do what you want (with a lot of template boilerplate and some exceptions) for aggregate classes by inspecting whether aggregate initialization works (with appropriate restrictions on type conversion) and leaves no empty elements, but I think that is as far as is possible. (For standard-layout classes you might also be able to derive the size from member type and order by calculation from the ABI spec.)

But actually, even standard-layout does not work in general because one needs to know the types of bases in order to determine layout in edge cases where members and bases have the same type (recursively).

I don't think you can guaranty that you don't omit members from size: padding and alignment (bool b would probably be in padding, so won't take extra space).

"we can assume that Fields are passed in the same order as they appear in S declaration" I don't see how ensuring that without ensuring all are present.

@Jarod42 I mean that it's ok if the calculated size is wrong and static_assert fires if fields are passed in wrong order.

@Fareanor sizeof operator gives only stack memory. I also need to count heap memory used by fields, this is what calcClassSize does. It iterates over the passed list of fields and adds up all types of memory used by that fields. E.g. in case of field of std::unique_ptr<T> type, it will add sizeof(unique_ptr) + sizeof(T)

When working with classes which require a tuple_view, I tend to provide one: auto as_tuple() { return std::tie(member1, member2/*, ..*/); }.

@user17732522 What if we assume that the first passed field is always correct. Then calculating the offset of this field will take care of base classes and vtable pointers, right?

@Jarod42 ok, but then you can forget to add field to as_tuple when you add a field to the class? so this doesn't really solve the problem

C++ doesn't have reflexivity (yet), boost::PFR/magic_get allow some introspection for some kind of classes (yours don't enter in that categories). So you have to workaround. as_tuple is one way, using some BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_STRUCT/Boost.Hana might be another one (you cannot forget a member as you use it to define the class).
